# Removing all records where one condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a table like below:

| ID | section | Yes_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EE_1 | sec_21 | Y |
| EE_1 | sec_23 | N |
| EE_1 | sec_22 | N |
| EE_2 | sec_21 | N |

I'm looking for a way to return ONLY IDs where there is NO 'Y' in the "Yes_no" column. Desired output below:

| ID | section | Yes_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EE_2 | sec_21 | N |

Comment: @squillman I think I'm explaining the question poorly. When I use SELECT DISTINCT, I return both IDs (EE_1 & EE_2). Because there are instances where EE_1 is both a Y/N value

Comment: Its because EE_1 has both Y and N! If that ID has only Y or both Y & N, then remove that record in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions are usually the fastest for this kind of thing

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID,
  t.section,
  t.Yes_no
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CountY = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Yes_no = 'Y' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE CountY = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6388926855e3aa060134e37f309ecb30)

Comment: I just ask because I want to learn more... why is faster a COUNT than a NOT EXISTS? I guessed the COUNT was precisely the slowest one, because it has to count all the records (while a NOT EXISTS finishes as soon as it find the first record that matches). Thank you

Comment: No, this is a windowed count. Each batch of rows with the same `ID` is counted together, the table is only scanned once. Whereas the `NOT EXISTS` is an anti-join, and every row is checked for the existence of other rows, the table is therefore accessed twice per row

Comment: Upvoted your answer!!! Thank you for the masterclass ;)

Comment: this solution works, thank you for the assistance Carlos & Charlieface

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
create table MyTable(
  ID varchar(10),
  section varchar(50),
  Yes_no varchar(1)
)
insert into MyTable values 
('EE_1','sec_21','Y'),
('EE_1','sec_23','N'),
('EE_1','sec_22','N'),
('EE_2','sec_21','N')

select *
from MyTable t1
where t1.Yes_no = 'N' and not exists
(select * from MyTable t2 where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.Yes_no = 'Y')
```

DBFiddler: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b24198e227588df323c579facd37153

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_X where ID not in (Select ID from table_X where Yes_no ='Y')
```

[Running example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjzu7AUJE8js2by2mEJUJU/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` keyword to perform this query because `exists` has better performance than `in`.

```
select *
from Table t
where t.Yes_no = 'N' and not exists
(select * from Table b where b.ID = b.ID and b.Yes_no = 'Y')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: you can use "exists" keyword to perform this query because "exists" has better performance than "in"

Comment: I meant you should [edit] your post to add more information. But it's OK, I edited it for you to add the information you provided in your comment.